# How to add user to openstack project in keystoneclient api v3 using python

Tags: python, openstack

I am using `openstack` keystoneclient api `v3` with python bindings
What is the way to add an existing user to a project with certain role.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a user to a project with a role as below:

```
from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session
from keystoneclient.v3 import client

# Admin credentials
AUTH_URL = 'http://192.0.0.10:35357/v3'
USER_ID = 'abd78a0b166e47eb8fe40381853f3d90'
PASSWORD = 'password'
PROJECT_ID = '5a56b817ec7342a9a6c0eea26f591621'

auth = v3.Password(auth_url=AUTH_URL,  user_id=USER_ID, password=PASSWORD, project_id=PROJECT_ID)
sess = session.Session(auth=auth)
keystone = client.Client(session=sess)


# User, role and project details
ROLE_ID = '7836dac8513745a6be2c9cf5df4640c9'
USER_ID = '7b96131d69b141be8d8d6749ef0e0168'
PROJECT_ID = '121088df9f364c8a92541f969c971b3e'

keystone.roles.grant(ROLE_ID, USER_ID, PROJECT_ID)
```

Reference link - https://docs.openstack.org/python-keystoneclient/latest/api/keystoneclient.v3.html#module-keystoneclient.v3.roles

Comment: @deepdive: Did you verify this answer? If it worked, please upvote/accept the answer

Comment: Suppose I want to have different projects for different users, do I have to create a role for each user?

Comment: You can assign the same role to different users of different projects. So, you do not have to create a role for each user